# Form validation using filter_var

Tags: javascript

I am working on an assignment using javascript. I am attempting to use filter_var to test if my form has empty fields but I cannot get it to run.

I'm not confident that my Syntax is right.

```
function validate_reg_form(form)
{
    var form = "";
    if (filter_var(form, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) 
    {
        alert("validate_reg_form() not yet implemented");//remove this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter_var` [is a PHP function](https://php.net/filter_var). It does not exist in JavaScript. The *exact* equivalent is:

```
var truthyBooleanStrings = ['1', 'true', 'on', 'yes'];

function validateRegForm(form) {
    var form = '';

    if (truthyBooleanStrings.indexOf(form) !== -1) {
        // …
    }
}
```

Maybe that’s not the right approach for

> test if my form has empty fields

, though. If you want to test that something is not an empty string, just use `!== ''` or the implicit truthiness of non-empty strings, as in

```
if (form) {
    // Not empty!
}
```

Comment: I am instructed to use filter_var. How will I accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: @user2504710: Pretty much in the way you wrote it, but in PHP, not JavaScript…